# How to utilise more cores when I am cpu mining?

Tags: bitcoin-core, litecoin

This is purely an experiment for fun. This is for litecoins but can bitcoin people help me too :)

I am using litecoinqt to solo cpu mine, on my windows machine. Threads set between 4 and 10, scantime of 99.

My main computer has 4 cpu cores. But I am noticing the same speed as when I use my laptop which has only one cpu core. This makes me think I am not using all the cores on my main computer?

Is there a way to force the miner to use more cores?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know about Litecoin-Qt but for a better result and to configure correctly the numer of threads I recommend you to use a software dedicated to LTC mining.

You can use https://github.com/pooler/cpuminer for only CPU and https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=150331.0 for GPU.

You must have a pool but you can solo mine with the arg '-server' when launchin litecoin-qt.

I know it's more difficult than just use the LiteCoin-Qt miner but it is also more configurable and more efficient.